# Convert tablefootnotes and footnotemark/text to endnotes

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I'm having to convert all my footnotes to endnotes, which has largely gone smoothly; the only exception are the footnotes which I've had to add to tables through either `\tablefootnote` or the combination `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` (I've had to use both in different tables).

As the following example shows, these retain their own numbering and remain footnotes; I need them to be properly numbered and formatted as endnotes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true, useprefix=false,
  shorthandibid, shorthandfull,
  addendum=false, notetype=endonly
]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{lastname19,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
title = {Article Title},
journal = {Prestigious Journal},
volume = {24},
pages = {1--78},
date = {2019},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.\autocite{lastname19}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Place & Number\footnotemark\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Distribution of orders to officials within Brittany, 1341–1364}
\label{table:bretonofficials}
\end{table}
\footnotetext{Some sources.}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Place & Number\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Distribution of orders to officials within Brittany, 1341–1364\tablefootnote{More sources.}}
\label{table:bretonofficials}
\end{table}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I am aware of the problems with having 'true' notes in tables instead of using something like `threeparttable` to produce table notes, but for a variety of reasons these do need to be actual notes. However, if it's not possible to get `\footnotemark/text` and/or `\tablefootnote` to behave as endnotes, I'd be curious for any other way to get these notes into the tables.

Comment: Using `\let\footnotemark=\endnotemark \let\footnotetext=\endnotetext \let\tablefootnote=\endnote` works fine.  The problem has to do with how memoir defines \caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is how  `\caption` processes arguments, producing multiple footnotes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true, useprefix=false,
  shorthandibid, shorthandfull,
  addendum=false, notetype=endonly
]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\let\footnotemark=\endnotemark
\let\footnotetext=\endnotetext
\let\tablefootnote=\endnote

%\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{lastname19,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
title = {Article Title},
journal = {Prestigious Journal},
volume = {24},
pages = {1--78},
date = {2019},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

Some text.\autocite{lastname19}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Place & Number\tablefootnote{Some sources.}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Distribution of orders to officials within Brittany, 1341–1364}
\label{table:bretonofficials}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Place & Number\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Distribution of orders to officials within Brittany, 1341–1364\textsuperscript{\ref{foot:bretonofficials}}]% for \listoftables
  {Distribution of orders to officials within Brittany, 1341–1364\footnotemark}
\label{table:bretonofficials}
\end{table}
\footnotetext{More sources.\label{foot:bretonofficials}}%  Note, label generated by \thendnotes

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for future reference, if there are multiple `\footnotemark`s in one table, it will give them all the same number, so `\tablefootnote` works better in that case.

Comment: Just for future reference, if there are multiple `\footnotemark`s in one table, it will give them all the same number, so `\tablefootnote` works better in that case.